# Chaining routes in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If a user clicks on a certain restaurant I want it to show the reviews for that restaurant, and the controller and model and everything working for the review. Is it possible to say like `/all/:id` to get the reviews?

I think I will need make a new view. Will that will fix the problem or is there is a way to do it without even adding a new view?

Thanks, and sorry for the nooby questions; I am brand new to Express and node.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express'),
app = express(),
es6Renderer = require('express-es6-template-engine'),
rootController = require('./routes/restaruants');
allRestaruantsController = require('./routes/allTheRestaruants');
reviewController = require('./routes/reviewController');

app.engine('html', es6Renderer);
app.set('views','views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('Power level over 9000');
});

app.use('/', rootController);
app.use('/all', allRestaruantsController);
app.use('/all/:id', reviewController);
```

**reviewController.js**

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    reviewModel = require('../models/reviewModel');

router.get('/'), async (req, res) => { 
    let restaruantData = [];
    restaruantData = await reviewModel.getReviewsById()


    res.render ('template', {
        locals: {
            title: 'All The Restaruants',
            dataArray: restaruantData
        },
        partials : {
            partial: 'partial-all'
        }
});
}

module.exports = router;
```

**reviewModel.js**

```
const db = require('./conn')

class ReviewByList {
    constructor(review) {
        this.review = review;
    }

    static async getReviewsById() {
        try {
            const response = await db.any(`SELECT restaruant.name, review.review FROM restaruant INNER JOIN review ON restaruant.id = review.restaruant_id`);
            console.log(response)
            return response;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('ERROR', error);
            return error;
        }
    }
}

module.exports = ReviewByList;
```

Also here is the partial that it uses:

```
<H1> Restaurants around the block</H1>
<ul>
    ${dataArray.map(item =>
        `<li><a class="all" href ='/all/${item.id}'>${item.name}</a> Address: ${item.address}</li>`
    ).join('')}
</ul>
```

I have confirmed that the review does work in the partial.

Comment: You decide weather or not to use a new view based on what page you want to show. Not what data you want to show. If you want to show the reviews on the same page as the restaurant then don't use a new view. If you want to show reviews on a different page then use a new view. If you want to serve a review via ajax then use a new view (consider each ajax response as its own "page"). This is a question that nobody but you (or your web/UX designer/artist) can answer. It is not a technical question but a design question

Comment: @slebetman okay, thank you for the information.